# Update Password page in AD FS without workplace join

Tags: adfs

I'm setting up AD FS on Windows Server 2012 R2. I would like to enable the update password feature, but without joining the devices to workplace. Microsoft has stated it's a requirement, in this article 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn280950.aspx

But I'm wondering if there way to skip the workplace join, as some devices are already joined to another domain

Comment: "Workplace join" != "Domain join"
see: http://scug.be/sccm/2014/05/20/workplace-join-with-adfs-3-0-device-registration-services-and-our-workplace-join-hitman-powershell-app-to-the-rescue/

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has published a hotfix allowing this now:
http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3035025